# Understanding ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener in Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio Iguana 2023.2.1, I encountered the following code snippet within the onCreate() method of an Android Java project:

```
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
    Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
    v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
    return insets;
});
```

I am relatively new to Android development and I'm having trouble understanding what this code does. Can someone please provide an explanation of each line and how it contributes to the functionality of the application? Additionally, any insights into the significance of `ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener` in this context would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!